# Type Error, How can I solve this error, In the image I wrote my specific question

Tags: python, class, typeerror, google-colaboratory

This is my first question.
I've solving my Python homework, Making the information of Korean Subway.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spKK8.png)

In the image, I wrote an question.
How can I solve this Error?

```
class SubwayLine:
    def __init__(self, stations):
        self.stations = stations
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(stations)
    
    
keys = ['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4']
values = subwayStation
subwayStation = {}
for line, stations in zip(keys, values):
    subwayStation[line] = SubwayLine(stations)
    
print(subwayStation['Line1'])
```

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

check your `values` variable you are passing subwayStations not real stations name like you have commented. Next time paste code not image. small suggestion choose variable name according to their nature like keys and values use in dict so avoid that and their will be one station so use station not stations in class.

```
class SubwayLine:
    def __init__(self,stations):
        self.stations = stations

    def __str__(self):
        return str(stations)



keys = ['Line1']
values = ['Seoul']
subwayStation = {}

for line,stations in zip(keys,values):
    subwayStation[line] = SubwayLine(stations)

print(subwayStation['Line1'])
```

Answer (score -1):

The TypeError is raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type.

Change the variable name of your dictionary it's conflicting with your values list.

Do not post pictures of code, please follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) while asking the question.

Comment: This should have been a comment.  It's not an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment but yes it should have been a comment